# Button IsEnabled never changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, frontend

This is my Button declaration, written in .xaml file:

```
<dxlc:LayoutGroup Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="5,15,0,5">
    <Grid MinWidth="100">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button 
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsSearchCriteriaHasValue}" 
            Content="Search" 
            MaxHeight="25" 
            MaxWidth="70" 
            ClipToBounds="True"  
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"                  
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
            Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</dxlc:LayoutGroup>
```

This is the function that returns true/false whether the user has typed any search text in the search box next to the search button. The function is in another .cs file:

```
public bool isButtonEnabled
{
    return (SearchBox.Selection.Count > 0);
}
```

The problem is that the value of isEnabled never changes, it stays true, i.e. the button stays enabled all the time or if I change the > sign, the button stays disabled all the time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `IsSearchCriteriaHasValue` needs to raise an event that it changed, you can do that by using `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    // Your property
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
           _Name = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write trigger for button (SearchBox looks a UI control)

> ```
> <Style TargetType="Button">
>   <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
>   <Style.Triggers>       
>     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selection.Count, ElementName=SearchBox}" Value="0">   !--  You can use convertor also
>      <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
>     </DataTrigger>
>   </Style.Triggers>
> </Style>   </Button.Style> </Button>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Its not problem with XAML, its problem with notification. I hope you are aware of INotifyProperty interface's NotifyPropertyChanged Event. Only if that is triggered for a property in ViewModel, then the UI will get the notification and updates it.

If SearchBox.Selection count changes, it doesnt trigger any notification for IsSearchCriteriaHasValue property that it has been changed and the UI should update.

Lets say SearchBox.Selection is bound to a observableCollection and the collection changes, then subscribed to the observableCollection for add/remove then trigger `NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSearchCriteriaHasValue")`; there.

Answer (score 1):

Binding works on property changed event. Your `ViewModel` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

An exemple:

```
// This form demonstrates using a BindingSource to bind 
// a list to a DataGridView control. The list does not 
// raise change notifications. However the DemoCustomer type  
// in the list does. 
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // This button causes the value of a list element to be changed. 
    private Button changeItemBtn = new Button();

    // This DataGridView control displays the contents of the list. 
    private DataGridView customersDataGridView = new DataGridView();

    // This BindingSource binds the list to the DataGridView control. 
    private BindingSource customersBindingSource = new BindingSource();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set up the "Change Item" button.
        this.changeItemBtn.Text = "Change Item";
        this.changeItemBtn.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.changeItemBtn.Click +=
            new EventHandler(changeItemBtn_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.changeItemBtn);

        // Set up the DataGridView.
        customersDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        this.Controls.Add(customersDataGridView);

        this.Size = new Size(400, 200);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create and populate the list of DemoCustomer objects 
        // which will supply data to the DataGridView.
        BindingList<DemoCustomer> customerList = new BindingList<DemoCustomer>();
        customerList.Add(DemoCustomer.CreateNewCustomer());
        customerList.Add(DemoCustomer.CreateNewCustomer());
        customerList.Add(DemoCustomer.CreateNewCustomer());

        // Bind the list to the BindingSource. 
        this.customersBindingSource.DataSource = customerList;

        // Attach the BindingSource to the DataGridView. 
        this.customersDataGridView.DataSource =
            this.customersBindingSource;

    }

    // Change the value of the CompanyName property for the first  
    // item in the list when the "Change Item" button is clicked.
    void changeItemBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get a reference to the list from the BindingSource.
        BindingList<DemoCustomer> customerList =
            this.customersBindingSource.DataSource as BindingList<DemoCustomer>;

        // Change the value of the CompanyName property for the  
        // first item in the list.
        customerList[0].CustomerName = "Tailspin Toys";
        customerList[0].PhoneNumber = "(708)555-0150";
    }

}

// This is a simple customer class that  
// implements the IPropertyChange interface. 
public class DemoCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // These fields hold the values for the public properties. 
    private Guid idValue = Guid.NewGuid();
    private string customerNameValue = String.Empty;
    private string phoneNumberValue = String.Empty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // The constructor is private to enforce the factory pattern. 
    private DemoCustomer()
    {
        customerNameValue = "Customer";
        phoneNumberValue = "(312)555-0100";
    }

    // This is the public factory method. 
    public static DemoCustomer CreateNewCustomer()
    {
        return new DemoCustomer();
    }

    // This property represents an ID, suitable 
    // for use as a primary key in a database. 
    public Guid ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idValue;
        }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerNameValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.customerNameValue)
            {
                this.customerNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneNumberValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.phoneNumberValue)
            {
                this.phoneNumberValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Binding works on property changed event. Your ViewModel should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. And you need to raise property changed event in property set. Or Simply you can use `delegate command` and write enable disable logic in CanExecute Method.
please refer this link for more info
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/179129/MVVM-Enable-Disable-button-via-a-PropertyChanged-e